# Is there a simple select query that satisfies two TRUE conditions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with records

```
FacilityID   StatusID    PaymentDuedate             EXPdate
0015617       1         2020-07-01 00:00:00.000    2020-06-30
0015617       2         2018-07-01 00:00:00.000    2020-06-30
0015617       5         2018-07-01 00:00:00.000    2020-06-30
```

Select single record for record status in (1,2) and latest Payment due date record

Tried below but it satisfies 2 conditions as TRUE and result set is 2 records. Is there any way. I only need as SQL VIEW. Application doesn't support stored PROC.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       l.facility_id,
       [Report_Status_Id],
       MAX(payment_due_date) AS payment_due_date,
       CONVERT(date, DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, l.Expiration_Date), 0))) AS EXPdate
FROM a_license l
     JOIN (SELECT facility_id,
                  MAX(payment_due_date) AS payment_due_date,
                  [Report_Status_Id]
           FROM a_facility_annual_report
           GROUP BY facility_id,
                    [Report_Status_Id]) ar ON l.facility_id = ar.facility_id --and ar.payment_due_date=l.Expiration_Date
WHERE ar.[Report_Status_Id] IN (1, 2)
  AND l.facility_id IN ('0015617')
GROUP BY l.facility_id,
         [Report_Status_Id],
         Expiration_Date;

Output I need

    FacilityID    PaymentDuedate             EXPdate
     0015617    2020-07-01 00:00:00.000    2020-06-30
```

Comment: *"I want to send single notification for record status in (1,2) and latest Payment due date record"* What do you mean by this? What are your expected results here? *Also, please learn to use white space and line breaks, your SQL is **very** difficult to read. Also, having a `DISTINCT` and a `GROUP BY` is either redundant or means your `GROUP BY` clause is incorrect.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CROSS APPLY with a TOP 1 :

```
SELECT 
       l.facility_id,
       [Report_Status_Id],
       MAX(payment_due_date) AS payment_due_date,
       CONVERT(date, DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, l.Expiration_Date), 0))) AS EXPdate
FROM a_license l
CROSS APPLY     (SELECT TOP 1
            facility_id,
                    payment_due_date,
                    [Report_Status_Id]
           FROM a_facility_annual_report afar
       WHERE l.facility_id = afar.facility_id
           ORDER BY payment_due_date  DESC) ar 

WHERE ar.[Report_Status_Id] IN (1, 2)
  AND l.facility_id IN ('0015617')
GROUP BY l.facility_id,
         [Report_Status_Id],
         Expiration_Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using case statement to consolidate status (1,2) into a single state 1.  If you haven't used a case statement before in sql, this can unlock quite a few options.

```
drop table t1
go
create table t1 (
Status int
)
go
insert into t1 values (1)
insert into t1 values (2)
go
select 
    case when status = 1 then 1 when status = 2 then 1 else 2 end, count(*)
from t1 
where 
    case when status = 1 then 1 when status = 2 then 1 else 2 end = 1
group by 
    case when status = 1 then 1 when status = 2 then 1 else 2 end
```